# Global Data Holder in OSGi

Tags: singleton, osgi, osgi-bundle

I need to use a global data value between a couple of OSGi modules. What's the best way to use a singleton data property holder in OSGi modules?

Should I design a "common" module, which exports a package and store global singleton in this common module package?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit how complex the initialisation of the data is. If you simply want to share some kind of constant then a singleton in a shared module is a good choice.

In other cases the loading is more involved. For example if you load the data from a database and loading might have other dependencies like a DataSource. In these cases it is better to just share an interface and a service. This then allows to hide the dependencies and initialisation effort from users of the service.

Comment: It needs some configuration and loading mechanism. I thing it should be design as a service. Thank you, it was helpful.